# Representation of infinite group having finite image

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Let G be infinte group and  $\phi$: G $\longrightarrow$ $GLn(\Bbb{C})$ be any representation such that image set of $\phi$ is finite, ( i.e. $Im\phi$ is finite set.)

Questions are

1) Is this representation is completely reducible? (if yes hint for proof)

2) Is this representation is always unitary representation? (if yes hint for proof)

Maschke's theorem said that every representation of a finite group is completely reducible. (But in our case G is infinite group)

Comment: This is indistinguishable from a representation of the finite group $G/ker(\phi)$.

Comment: You mean that if any representation has finite image then "Maschke's theorem" still holds, there is no need of condition on group to be finite.? @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: More generally, a homomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ factors through $G/\ker\phi\rightarrow Im(\phi)\subset H$; conversely any homomorphism $G\rightarrow H$ with finite image factors through some finite quotient of $G$. So the class of representations you're considering is simply the class of representations which factor through a finite quotient; this means that they can be identified with representations of this finite quotient, so they're completely reducible and unitary. (The "fancy" way of answering your question is that yes; Maschke's theorem holds for such representations...

Comment: because they're obtained via pullback from some finite quotient).